# Scraping Woeidlookup.com for WOEID

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make more or less a weather checker. I am scraping Yahoo for this, as I cannot figure out how to use their API plus it seems like more fun to me. I haven't been coding using Python3 for very long. All of this code is being done on a RPI the version of Python3 it uses is 3.4.2.

The issue I have ran across is getting the WOEID number. I figured scraping Woeidlookup.com would be an easy task to get the number. However, now after trying various ways to get the data from the site I am here. I do not have any code to show for scraping this website as if it didn't work I just deleted it.

I am sure that someone on here knows how to input the required text into the 
 field of the website and then submit it. Once it is submitted I have to scrape the table that shows up below the  field to get the WOEID number.

I have already completed the scrape for Yahoo weather which is posted below. Any critiques on the code for learning purposes would be appreciated. I have found a ton of useful information on this site the past few weeks and all of that knowledge for the most part went into this project. The pandas import is if I decide to add in a table later on instead of the current print() setup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime

baseurl = "https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather"
Country = input("Country : ").replace(" ", "-")
State = input("State : ").replace(" ", "-")
Town = input("Town : ").replace(" ", "-")
WOEID = "" # this is what I need to figure out

url = '%(U)s/%(C)s/%(S)s/%(T)s-%(W)s' % {'U': baseurl, "C": Country, "S": State, "T": Town, "W": WOEID}

now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = 0
minute = now.minute
AMPM = ""
ToD = ""

page = requests.get(url)
code =  page.status_code
content = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
weather = soup.find(class_="weather")
temp = soup.find(class_="temperature Fz(14px) Tsh($temperature-text-shadow)")
wind = weather.find(id="weather-wind")
sunMoon = weather.find(id='weather-sun-moon')
details = weather.find(id="weather-detail")
detail = details.find(class_="detail")
start = detail.find_all(class_="Fl(start)")
end = detail.find_all(class_="Fl(end)")
desc = detail.find(class_="description Py(10px) Px(4px) Fz(1em)")
dayNight = desc.find_all(class_="day-description My(10px)")
windText = wind.find('span', {'data-reactid': '455'}).text
windSpeedDir = wind.find('p', {'data-reactid': '456'}).text
baro = wind.find('span', {'data-reactid': '461'}).text
pressure = wind.find('p', {'data-reactid': '462'}).text
phase = sunMoon.find('div', {'data-reactid': '504'}).text
dayDesc = temp.find(class_="description Va(m) Px(2px) Fz(1.3em)--sm Fz(1.6em)")
currentTemp = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '37'}).text
degreeSymbol = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '38'}).text
high = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '29'}).text
low = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '33'}).text
city = weather.find(class_="city Fz(2em)--sm Fz(3.7em)--lg Fz(3.3em) Fw(n) M(0) Trsdu(.3s) desktop_Lh(1) smartphone_Lh(1)")
country = weather.find(class_="Fz(1.2em)--sm Fz(2em)--lg Fz(1.5em) Fw(200) country Trsdu(.3s) Lh(2.5)")
dateTime = weather.find(class_="Lts(1px) Fz(14px) Fs(i) Lh(2.5) Fw(300) Tsh($temperature-text-shadow)")

try:
    sunrise = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '510'}).text
except:
    sunrise = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '515'}).text
try:
    sunset = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '511'}).text
except:
    sunset = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '516'}).text

sunrise1 = sunrise.split(" ")
sunrise2 = sunrise1[0].split(":")
srHour = int(sunrise2[0])
srMinute = int(sunrise2[1])
sunset1 = sunset.split(" ")
sunset2 = sunset1[0].split(":")
ssHour = int(sunset2[0])
ssMinute = int(sunset2[1])

if now.hour > 12:
    hour = now.hour - 12
    AMPM = "PM"
else:
    hour = now.hour
    AMPM = "AM"

if now.hour >= srHour and now.hour < 12:
    ToD = "morning"
if now.hour >= 12 and now.hour - 12 < ssHour:
    ToD = "afternoon"
if now.hour > 12 and now.hour - 12 >= ssHour:
    ToD = "night"

print('Weather data for the city of', city.get_text(), 'in the country of', country.get_text())
print('Today is', "%02d" % (now.month), '/', "%02d" % (now.day), '/', now.year)
print('The current time is', "%02d" % (hour), ":", "%02d" % (now.minute), ":", "%02d" % (now.second), AMPM)
print('Right now it is a', dayDesc.get_text().lower(), ToD, 'sky.')
print('It is currently', currentTemp, degreeSymbol, 'F.')
print('The high for today is', high, 'F.')
print('The low for today is', low, 'F.')
print(start[0].get_text(), ' : ', end[0].get_text())
print(start[1].get_text(), '   : ', end[1].get_text())
print(start[2].get_text(), ' : ', end[2].get_text())
print(start[3].get_text(), '   : ', end[3].get_text())
print(windText, "       : ", windSpeedDir)
print(baro, "  : ", pressure)
print("Moon Phase  : ", phase)
print("Sunrise     : ", sunrise)
print("Sunset      : ", sunset)
print(dayNight[0].get_text())
print(dayNight[1].get_text())
```

Comment: The way I am seeing this is I have two ways to get the result I want.
1. Use some sort of API addon for python to click the change location button on the webpage which reveals the code for the rest of what I already have.
2. Figure out how to grab the WOEID from the website I was talking about based on zip code only inputs.

Preferably I would like Option 1 based on what I have seen so far with trying to interact with the other's input area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much coding, searching etc.. I have fixed the problem I was having by using a different website to get the WOEID and data. Here below are the completed scripts I made for the base of the project I am working on for school. I split it into 3 files and it is undocumented throughout the code, but it should be fairly easy to follow. Hopefully this helps someone who is also doing something like this even if it is probably coded poorly.

Main Script

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import WeatherAppBS4_Woeid as woeid

baseurl = "https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather"
Country = woeid.Country.replace(" ", "-")
State = woeid.State.replace(" ", "-")
Town = woeid.Town.replace(" ", "-")
WOEID = woeid.WOEID

url = '%(U)s/%(C)s/%(S)s/%(T)s-%(W)s' % {'U': baseurl, "C": Country, "S": State, "T": Town, "W": WOEID}

now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = 0
minute = now.minute
AMPM = ""
ToD = ""

page = requests.get(url)
code =  page.status_code
content = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
weather = soup.find(class_="weather")
temp = soup.find(class_="temperature Fz(14px) Tsh($temperature-text-shadow)")
wind = weather.find(id="weather-wind")
sunMoon = weather.find(id='weather-sun-moon')
details = weather.find(id="weather-detail")
detail = details.find(class_="detail")
start = detail.find_all(class_="Fl(start)")
end = detail.find_all(class_="Fl(end)")
desc = detail.find(class_="description Py(10px) Px(4px) Fz(1em)")
dayNight = desc.find_all(class_="day-description My(10px)")
windText = wind.find('span', {'data-reactid': '455'}).text
windSpeedDir = wind.find('p', {'data-reactid': '456'}).text
baro = wind.find('span', {'data-reactid': '461'}).text
pressure = wind.find('p', {'data-reactid': '462'}).text
phase = sunMoon.find('div', {'data-reactid': '504'}).text
dayDesc = temp.find(class_="description Va(m) Px(2px) Fz(1.3em)--sm Fz(1.6em)")
currentTemp = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '37'}).text
degreeSymbol = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '38'}).text
high = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '29'}).text
low = temp.find('span', {'data-reactid': '33'}).text
city = weather.find(class_="city Fz(2em)--sm Fz(3.7em)--lg Fz(3.3em) Fw(n) M(0) Trsdu(.3s) desktop_Lh(1) smartphone_Lh(1)")
country = weather.find(class_="Fz(1.2em)--sm Fz(2em)--lg Fz(1.5em) Fw(200) country Trsdu(.3s) Lh(2.5)")
dateTime = weather.find(class_="Lts(1px) Fz(14px) Fs(i) Lh(2.5) Fw(300) Tsh($temperature-text-shadow)")

try:
    sunrise = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '510'}).text
except:
    sunrise = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '515'}).text
try:
    sunset = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '511'}).text
except:
    sunset = sunMoon.find('span', {'data-reactid': '516'}).text

sunrise1 = sunrise.split(" ")
sunrise2 = sunrise1[0].split(":")
srHour = int(sunrise2[0])
srMinute = int(sunrise2[1])
sunset1 = sunset.split(" ")
sunset2 = sunset1[0].split(":")
ssHour = int(sunset2[0])
ssMinute = int(sunset2[1])

if now.hour > 12:
    hour = now.hour - 12
    AMPM = "PM"
else:
    hour = now.hour
    AMPM = "AM"

if now.hour >= srHour and now.hour < 12:
    ToD = "morning"
if now.hour >= 12 and now.hour < ssHour:
    ToD = "afternoon"
if now.hour > 12 and now.hour >= ssHour:
    ToD = "night"

print('Weather data for the city of', city.get_text(), 'in the country of', country.get_text())
print('Today is', "%02d" % (now.month), '/', "%02d" % (now.day), '/', now.year)
print('The current time is', "%02d" % (hour), ":", "%02d" % (now.minute), ":", "%02d" % (now.second), AMPM)
print('Right now it is a', dayDesc.get_text().lower(), ToD, 'sky.')
print('It is currently', currentTemp, degreeSymbol, 'F.')
print('The high for today is', high, 'F.')
print('The low for today is', low, 'F.')
print(start[0].get_text(), ' : ', end[0].get_text())
print(start[1].get_text(), '   : ', end[1].get_text())
print(start[2].get_text(), ' : ', end[2].get_text())
print(start[3].get_text(), '   : ', end[3].get_text())
print(windText, "       : ", windSpeedDir)
print(baro, "  : ", pressure)
print("Moon Phase  : ", phase)
print("Sunrise     : ", sunrise)
print("Sunset      : ", sunset)
print(dayNight[0].get_text())
print(dayNight[1].get_text())
```

WOEID Script

```
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import WeatherAppMECH as mech

page = requests.get(mech.url)
code =  page.status_code
content = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
search = soup.find(id="content")
results = search.find('div', {'id': 'lookup_result'})

rows=list()
for tr in results.find('table', {'id':'woeid_results_table'}):
    for td in tr:
        rows.append(td.string)
resultList=rows[1:]

Town = resultList[0]
State = resultList[1]
Country = resultList[2]
WOEID = resultList[3]
```

MechanicalSoup Script

```
import requests
import mechanicalsoup
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

browserurl = "http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz"
userInput = input('Town, state, country, address, zipcode or landmark : ').replace(',','%20').replace(' ','%20')
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open(browserurl)
browser.select_form('form[action="http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup"]')
browser["place"] = userInput

browser.close()

baseurl = "http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup"
url = '%(U)s/%(I)s' % {'U': baseurl, "I": userInput}
```

Comment: I will update this again after I figure out how to grab the current time of where I search.